# iOS 9: view is not rendered properly after I rotate device

Tags: swift, ios9

This is my custom `UIView`:

[image]

After I rotate to horizontal, and then back to Portrait it looks like this:

[image]

Why?

After I rotate device this method is called:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

What Am I doing wrong? It works perfect for ios8, but not for ios9

Comment: Do you need to call setNeedsDisplay ? If you have defined proper constraints, it should work in horizontal or vertical layout. Can you post your code where you create constraints ?

Comment: Every constraint I create in Interface Builder. And they are working fairly well with `iOS 8`, but not with `iOS 9`.